# EXEC xp_cmdshell with powersell 7 with query to send to telegram

Tags: powershell

I want to send telegram message from T-SQL query, I found away to send it from PowerShell 7 with [PoshGram](https://github.com/techthoughts2/PoshGram) and this is the normal script run in [powershell 7](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.1.3/PowerShell-7.1.3-win-x64.msi)

```
Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken "BotTokenN" -ChatID "ChatIDN" -Message "Hello"
```

I want to send query like

```
select * 
from table
```

to telegram chat and when I try a script like this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'pwsh -command  Import-Module PoshGram ;$token = "TokenN";$chat = "ChatN";Send-TelegramTextMessage -BotToken $token -ChatID $chat -Message "select * from table " '
```

I get an error

> [91m169:AAGlfLsdWTr2vqRTGW9VY0KH9o: [91mThe term '169:AAGlfLsdWTr2vqRTGW9VY0KH9o' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Any advice?

Comment: why not go the other way round? first use powershell to run the SQL query and then iterate the query result and run `Send-TelegramTextMessage`.

Comment: Any example I know poweshell can run sql query but how put the result of sql query in the powershell again.

Comment: the first example over from http://woshub.com/run-ms-sql-db-query-with-powershell/ shows how to query a sql server results being stored in the variable `$rows` which you then could iterate through.